# Google apps script : drop a document in My drive from a form in google site

Tags: google-apps-script

I use the following code to create a kind of dropbox for my students. The form is embedded on a google site page . When the file is sent in the "dropbox" folder, it is automatically converted in a text file. I did try with a .doc,  .xls and .pdf... 
Should it be possible to avoid this problem ?
Thanks a lot
Jean-Paul

```
var folderName = "Assignments-Spring-2011";

function doGet() {

  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("Upload Assignment");
  app.setHeight(180);
  var form = app.createFormPanel().setId('frm').setEncoding('multipart/form-data');
  var formContent = app.createGrid().resize(6,2);
  form.add(formContent);

  formContent.setWidget(1, 0, app.createLabel('Assignment Number:'));
  var assignmentNumberList = app.createListBox();
  assignmentNumberList.addItem("Assignment 1");
  assignmentNumberList.addItem("Assignment 2");
  assignmentNumberList.addItem("Assignment 3");
  assignmentNumberList.addItem("Assignment 4");
  assignmentNumberList.addItem("Assignment 5");
  assignmentNumberList.addItem("Assignment 6");
  assignmentNumberList.addItem("Assignment 7");
  assignmentNumberList.addItem("Assignment 8");

  formContent.setWidget(1, 1, assignmentNumberList.setName('assignmentNumber'));

  formContent.setWidget(3, 0, app.createLabel('Assignment File:'));
  formContent.setWidget(3, 1, app.createFileUpload().setName('thefile'));
  formContent.setWidget(5, 0, app.createSubmitButton('Submit Assignment!'));

  // thank you panel
  var panel = app.createSimplePanel().setVisible(false).setId("thankyouPanel");
  var label = app.createLabel("Thank you for submitting the         Assignment").setStyleAttribute("fontSize", "16px");
  panel.add(label);

  app.add(panel);
  app.add(form);

  return app;
}

function doPost(e) {
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var name = Session.getActiveUser().getUserLoginId();
  var assignmentFile = e.parameter.file;
  var uploadBlob = Utilities.newBlob        (assignmentFile, "text/plain",e.parameter.assignmentNumber+"-"+name+"-"+e.parameter.thefile.name );
  var doc = DocsList.createFile(uploadBlob);
  // get assignment folder
  var folder = DocsList.getFolder(folderName);
  doc.addToFolder(folder);

  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var form = app.getElementById("frm").setVisible(false);
  var panel = app.getElementById("thankyouPanel").setVisible(true);
  app.close();
  return app;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks as thought he code you've used is intentionally restricting it to text:

```
var uploadBlob = Utilities.newBlob        (assignmentFile, "text/plain",e.parameter.assignmentNumber+"-"+name+"-"+e.parameter.thefile.name );
```

Simply eliminate that line and redirect your variables like so

```
var uploadBlob = e.parameter.file;
```

Should set you straight.

Comment: ...the problem remains... I've read this : http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=582 but I don't find the solution.
How could we put "ContentType" in a variable and re-use it as secnd parameter in place of "text/plain" ???

Comment: Works when I make the adjustment.  Here's the doPost section '}

function doPost(e) {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var name = Session.getActiveUser().getUserLoginId();
  var fileName = e.parameter.assignmentNumber+"-"+name+"-"+e.parameter.thefile.name
  var doc = DocsList.createFile(e.parameter.thefile);
  doc.rename(fileName);
  // get assignment folder
  var folder = DocsList.getFolder(folderName);
  doc.addToFolder(folder);'

Comment: Oh, and you had to variables named 'doc'.

Comment: Well... thanks a lot ! It works fine. My students will be very happy ;o)... Jean-Paul (Belgium GMT+1... going to sleep)

Comment: He  went to sleep and never came back :-)  - May I suggest you put your code you gave in comment in your actual response for easier reading?  Thanks